# Pictures missing from odp file when reopening in Impress

Tags: libreoffice

In Impress 3.5.4.2 pictures are missing when reopening an odp presentation!

They weren't linked but saved in the odp-file.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be the following bug:

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50051 and

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46447